# Sourcing data from sharepoint list , get user input, create custom column and patch them to another sharepoint list in powerapps

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps

I am stuck in my thoughts on how to proceed with the solutioning of this problem. Please help out here.

I have two SharePoint lists

[image: source]

[image: target]

If you notice, target has same columns has source with 2 more additional columns.

manual-input will contain user input value and CalcCol will contain a calculated value.

The requirement is to create a power apps which will filter items based on title from reddit-source and show it in a gallery , then take user input and show dynamically the calculated value.

Once the user likes what he/she sees, then when they press submit button, the data should patch to reddit-target.

Below is what i created in powerapps

Enabled modern controls
Took a model control drop down , Linked with the code

[image]

Then took a blank vertical gallery , added modern text input in view mode except the third column as it will be in edit mode for user input.

The first two columns are linked directly to source thru item.column name, 2nd one is standalone and 4th columns is just concatenate from first three columns.

[image]

I am not sure on how to write the patch function which will only take first and 3rd column (as 2nd column didn't had any user input , we need to ignore that row) and patch to the target SharePoint.